# ANTLR4 Java plugin RegEx for duplicate tokens

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, antlr4

I'm writing a grammar in ANTLR4, and want to have a rule for an equation that can be either int or float, but not a mixture of both. So far I have:

```
equation: (INT | FLOAT) OPERATION (INT | FLOAT);
```

I have found a RegEx 'cheat sheet' [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html). This page states that '\1' indicates that it should have the same content as group 1.

However, when I tried this with Antlr it didn't work. Here's what I used:

```
equation: (INT|FLOAT) OPERATOR '\1';
```

So does anyone know a way I can check that group 2 is the same token as group 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Antltr way to handle this is to just directly specify what is acceptable:

```
equation : FLOAT OPERATION FLOAT    #eqFloat
         | INT   OPERATION INT      #eqInt
         ;
```

A mixed float/int operation will not be recognized. If a parse tree distinction between the two types of equation is not required, remove the alternate labels.